# Laravel 5.3-Limit login attempts default auth-Trait method hasTooManyLoginAttempts has not been applied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, traits

I am trying to implement limiting login attempts of default auth using `ThrottleLogins` trait

Here is my implementation in `Auth\LoginCotroller`

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers,ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    protected $maxLoginAttempts = 2; // Amount of bad attempts user can make
    protected $lockoutTime = 1;
}
```

But i will get the following error

> Trait method hasTooManyLoginAttempts has not been applied, because
>   there are collisions with other trait methods on
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AuthenticatesUsers` trait uses `ThrottlesLogins` in its definition so you already have `ThrottlesLogins` by having `AuthenticatesUsers`.

The `$maxLoginAttempts` and `$lockoutTime` aren't used by the trait. You could override `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` and adjust the attempts and decay time.

```
return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
    $this->throttleKey($request), $this->maxLoginAttempts, $this->lockoutTime
);
```

Comment: So i don't the thottlelogins trait anymore??

Comment: But the loginlimits not woking

Comment: Thanks let me try your answer

Answer (score 0):

The error says there is a collision between your traits. Now check the trait in your controller and the traits in your `User` Model. Remove any duplicates

Comment: There is no traits in user model

Comment: Remove `Throttleslogins` then. Both traits are colliding

Comment: Oh yes, you are using default Controller. Yep, the default controller already includes `Throttleslogins`. It's well mentioned in the doc. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: version is Laravel 5.3